# How to override Material-UI Popover styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I override the default value of the `max-height` property for the `Popover` component?

I tried to add `style={{'maxHeight': '365px'}}`, but nothing is changed:

```
<Popover
  style={{'maxHeight': '365px'}}
  className='notif-popover'
  open={this.state.notifOpen}
  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
>
```

Comment: Wanna check the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only props that apply style are:
`className` string of classes and `style` object with styles.
Remember that these are applied to the root element (the Modal component).

[Docs](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.14.4/#/components/popover) [SourceCode](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Popover/Popover.js) (if you're using v1-beta). You can see in the sources that the remaining props are passed to the Modal component

```
const {
  anchorEl,
  anchorReference,
  anchorPosition,
  anchorOrigin,
  children,
  classes,
  elevation,
  getContentAnchorEl,
  marginThreshold,
  onEnter,
  onEntering,
  onEntered,
  onExit,
  onExiting,
  onExited,
  open,
  PaperProps,
  role,
  transformOrigin,
  transitionClasses,
  transitionDuration,
  ...other
} = this.props;

<Modal show={open} BackdropInvisible {...other}>
```

You can see in the sources that MaterialUI uses the `withStyles` HoC from `react-jss` and has a styles object for the `Paper` component

```
export const styles = {
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    overflowY: 'auto',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    // So we see the popover when it's empty.
    // It's most likely on issue on userland.
    minWidth: 16,
    minHeight: 16,
    maxWidth: 'calc(100vw - 32px)',
    maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 32px)'
```

> maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 32px)'

This is bound to a class `paper` and then passed to the classes prop and applied to the `Paper` component.

**Solution**:

Use the `className` prop on the root element with nested selector that targets the `Paper` component (inspect and see on which element it applies the class).

Example of possible selector (should definitely use a better one, inspect element)

```
.rootElement > * { max-height: '375px' }
```

and then you'd do `<Popover className='rootElement' />`

Comment: And how can I override the default value of the `max-height` property?

Answer (score 2):

You should really override the style while building the theme...

```js
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTooltip: {
      tooltip: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Seems like most mui style override answers avoid dealing with the theme layer, I think it's because the documentation isn't all that great. But this should be the accepted correct answer.

Comment: Note: `createMuiTheme` is deprecated. One should use `createTheme` instead, but there is no `overrides` argument in this new function.

Answer (score -8):

This CSS override seems to work for me:

```
.writeYourOwnClasHere {
  .MuiPaper-root-6 {
    padding: 30px;
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

Btw, it's an unbelievably crappy API.

Comment: This won't work cause the id on the classname (`6` in this case) can change